# ODEs - Newton's Second Law

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So there's this question on a past exam I'm trying to work through, and its solution:

[image]

Is it possible to make it so that v'=-v^2? That was my first approach and then to integrate directly to get the general solution. But apparently I was supposed to solve it by separating.

So, how come that is the case? Is it not possible to get the solution with the antiderivative of v^2? In what case am I able to integrate to get the solution function of a differential equation?

Thanks.

Comment: Simply  integrate the last line on display with respect to $t$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is true that $\dfrac{dv}{dt}=-v^2$, what antiderivative are you speaking of (*cough* what variable of integration are you interested in *cough*)? You can get: $$v(t)=-\int [v(t)]^2~dt+C$$... which is not very helpful.

On the other hand, from $-v^{-2}\dfrac{dv}{dt}=1$ it follows: $$\int-\frac1{v^2}\frac{dv}{dt}dt=\int dt\\\int-v^{-2}dv=t+C\\\frac1v=t+C\\v(t)=\frac1{t+C}$$

Comment: Oh man, why didn't I see that? I actually feel kinda dumb now, haha. Thanks for that.